# return type array

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

Hello guys im newbie in C# Programming, i have problem when return array type in C# function. The return value its from query database(the code below):

```
 //determine list of lesson
    private string fillTreeLesson(string course_id)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost; database=moodle; user=root; password=";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "select name from lesson where course like '%"+course_id+"%'";
                cmnd.CommandText = sql;
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   lesson_name = reader.GetString("name");

                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return lesson_name;
    }
```

So my questions are:

1. I want to return type become array, can you give me advice?
2. How i can use above function, and call by index of return value. if i will call like these(fillTreeLesson is the name of function i will use):

   treeOutline.Nodes[counter_node].Nodes.Add(fillTreeLesson(course_name));

thanks for attention

Comment: It would really help if you could post the *complete* method - we can't see the declaration of the method or of `lesson_name`.

Comment: Discard 2nd question or post it separately. Ask one question in a post in well clarified manner (I also used to violate earlier on, so nothing to worry about - move your 2nd question as new question (in case you dont find it already here)

Comment: ok  @TalhaIrfan , thanks for advice i will separately this question.

Comment: @JonSkeet lesson_name declared as global in these class. i have updated for more completed method.thanks for your attention

Comment: I couldn't get your 2nd question yet. If you want to get all the elements of lesson name array/list separately, then you can do it using the solution I have proposed

Comment: It's really not at all clear where an array would come in here - or *why* `lesson_name` is an instance variable. You should also look into `using` statements, better exception handling, following .NET naming conventions, and using parameterized SQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it easily using a list as:

```
public List<string> FillTreeLesson(string course_id)
{

List<string> returnList = new List<string>(); 
    try
    {

        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();    
        string sql = "select name from lesson where course like '%"+course_id+"%'";
        cmnd.CommandText = sql;
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
          lesson_name = reader.GetString("name");
          returnList.Add(lesson_name);
    }
    con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

  return returnList;
}
```

In order to call this function,

Firstly make the *List* to contain your result:

```
List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
```

Then call the function and take its output in *namesList* we just
    created:

```
namesList = FillTreeLesson("CS-502");
```

After it, you can easily get those strings one by one using
    *foreach* loop:

```
foreach(string currentName in namesList)
{
//Whatever you want to do with currentName
}
```

*OR*

You can use for loop (*Preferable if you want to use them in some
    order using their index value or have to change their values later
    on*)

```
for(int i=0; i<namesList.Count; i++)
{

//Your code. You should access given element as namesList[i]

}
```

Comment: @Emil See Now Updated Answer